# Font settings not picked up in NextJS/React

Tags: reactjs, fonts, next.js, material-ui

I have a website I created where users can sign in.  The font of the title of my website is as expected with font "Carter One".   But when the user signs in, I see a font that I have not specified anywhere.

Interestingly, if I hit the Refresh button, the intended font will appear.  That being said, I suspect the issue is the intended font is only invoked on the server-side and some other font is used in a cache of some sort.

I'm using NextJS with Material UI.

#### Expected

[image: correct font]

#### Actual

[image: logo with wrong font]

[image: wrong font debugger]

From looking at the debugging tools in Chrome, the CSS file I'd expect to be referenced is overridden by a `<style>` component coming from the MUITypography tag.

#### utils.module.css

```css
.headerLogo {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: -0.05rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

#### global.css

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu,
    Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

#### user.js

```
...

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: { protected: true }
  }
}

export default function UserAccount() {
  
  ...
  
  return (
    <>
      {user &&
        <BaseLayout>
          <Box sx={{ mt: "3rem" }}>
            <Typography variant="h2">
              Welcome {user.displayName}!
            </Typography>
            <div className={utilStyles.subheaderLogo}>{user.email}</div>
          </Box>
        </BaseLayout>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

#### _app.js

```
...
import '../css/global.css'
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'

import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      '-apple-system', 'BlinkMacSystemFont', '"Open Sans"', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',].join(',')
  }
})

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a common mistake using MUI; you have to add this code to your root _app.js component:

```
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'

import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

## Caution !!!

If you are using MUI and next.js, you should also add jss to CSS and caching for your styles because MUI components use jss, and this jss runs in the client browser (not in the server) after pages load and will have a bad user experience. Here is MUI and next.js official tutorial for this issue https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/example-projects/

Comment: I still had the same result after adding these changes.  Should I define a theme?  So far I've only used `const theme = createTheme({ })` as the theme.   My fonts are defined the CSS.

Comment: where did you put your css imports?

Comment: I import my global.css in the _app.js file.  I added in the original question my _app.js.

Comment: did you follow tath official tutorial for this issue https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/example-projects/

Comment: Thank you, I followed the instructions at  https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/example-projects/ and this resolved my issue.  I had to add a lot of code but at least my fonts are consistent.